# Replace all Imgur URL with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

My blog stores images at Imgur, but it loads too slowly. Using JavaScript I want to replace all URLs of the form

`https://i.imgur.com/xxxxxx.png`

to

`https://example.net/imgur/xxxxxx.png`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any Javascript to do this, just create a folder in your directory where your blog site's files are and download the images and put them in that folder and it should work.

Comment: My blog uses too many images and my hosting doesn't have enough space for those images

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regex replacement:

```js
var url = "https://i.imgur.com/image.png";
var output = url.replace(/https:\/\/i.imgur.com\/(\S+)\.png/g, "https://example.net/imgur/$1.png");
console.log(url);
console.log(output);
```

Comment: How to replace all <img> tags using images from imgur

Comment: That's not the question you asked above nor is it what I have answered `:-)`

Comment: :) i want replece ALL url

Comment: Oh...then use `/g` in the call to `replace`, to tell JavaScript that you want a global replacement.